# Get old notification from FCM continuesly in my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send notification for downloading a file in my android app. When my app is not running and i send FCM then I get all the notifications that I send earlier and new one continuously.
How to overcome this?
Here is my MyFirebaseMessagingService class.

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
                Log.d("data", "onMessageReceived: firebase called");                 
                Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();                   
                String url = data.get("file_url");            
                Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent();
                broadcast_intent.putExtra(MainActivity.FIREBASE_URL, url);                    broadcast_intent.setAction(MainActivity.FIREBASE_URL_BROADCAST);
                sendBroadcast(broadcast_intent);            
            }

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";                  
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    }
```

Comment: Are notification come to your mobile phones or are they sending to your server too? Also have you perform your notification code in your _MainActivity_ class ?

Comment: Yes, notifications are coming in mobile phone.

Comment: I have not create any notification builder or not handle any notification event, then also notification is appear

Comment: What is the purpose of `sendBroadcast` in your code ? Because at anywhere you might be using custom brodcast receiver in your app

Comment: Broadcast is send for downloading a file from url which is sent through FCM

Comment: Its better to use DownloadManager to which will download your file with its own receiver ! Also it will take some time delay if there is a some network issue. So might be you'r getting notifications continuously!